# How can I solve the url pagination loop problem with Ansible?

Tags: json, loops, url, ansible, pagination

I need to send a URL query and return the JSON result, then read IP, username, password and use it as host.

And the first step of my problem is that there are multiple pages when I send a URL query and I will save the server information on all these pages as a host, then save the information from these pages as a host, access these servers, and update them.

`URL - http://apilink/virtual-machines`

page results JSON

```
"meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "count": 16, 
            "current_page": 1, 
            "links": {
                "next": "http://apilink/virtual-machines?page=2"
            }, 
            "per_page": 16, 
            "total": 169, 
            "total_pages": 11
        }
    }
```

I will continue to query with the **next URL** and I have to write the results on all returned pages as hosts.

```
"json": {
    "data": [
         {
            "actual_mhz": 0, 
            "connectionParameters": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "description": "Secure Shell", 
                        "ip_addr": "192.168.1.1", 
                        "port": 22, 
                        "protocol": "SSH"
                    }
                ]
            },  
            "hostname": "hostnameserver1", 
            "name": "server1", 
            "os": null, 
            "password": "xXxXxXxXX", 
            "status": "running", 
            "username": "root", 
         [
    },
```

From the result returned like this, I will use IP, username, password as host, access these hosts with the next task, and run the system update command.

Comment: That's a nice written requirement. Where is the code have written as an attempt to fulfill it and what is the error it generates or the problem you have with it ? Please edit your question to add more details. If you are totally lost, here are a few details that might help you (non exhaustive): you will have to use the `uri` and/or `get_url` modules to call the first page then loop `total_pages` time to call each uri again, register the result, and use that register through the `add_host` module. Looking forward to see some code samples.

Comment: I am already getting the first result with url get. I am troubled, I cannot move forward after here. I could not set up the loop. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would do a first API call, just to grab the `meta.pagination.total_pages`, then based on this value, I would use a couple `loop` and [`range`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#range), [which is the replacement of the `with_sequence`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence).

Then what you have to know is that when you register the result of a command, you can access the result of the previous items from the variable already.
There is only something to understand, this is the fact that Ansible is creating results in a very peculiar way:

1. The items are registered as if you where using no loop at all, and you can reference the previous element via your registered variable.
2. When you exist the loop, then the `results` key is created in the dictionary and then populated from all the results.

Something like:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: https://example.org/virtual-machines
      register: number_of_pages

    - uri: 
        url: >-
          {{ 
             api_call.json.meta.pagination.links.next 
             if api_call is defined else 'https://example.org/virtual-machines'
          }}
      loop: "{{ range(number_of_pages.json.meta.pagination.total_pages) }}"
      register: api_call

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ api_call }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply loop worked. but I can't read the data for later.